# Записать в массив только уникальные(повторяющиеся 1 раз) элементы

Tags: c++, c

Из массива А[length], записать в массив B[length] только числа которые повторяются в A[length] один раз и вывести на экран. Не могу допереть, как это реализовать. Ниже начал написал заполнение первого массива, но со вторым траблы.

```
int const length = 20;
int arr1[length];
cout << "Исходный массив: \n";
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    arr1[i] = -20 + rand() % 41;
    cout << arr1[i] << " ";
}
cout << "\n\n";

cout << "Результирующий массив: \n";
int arr_1[length];

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{

    for (int j = i+1; j < length; j++)
    {
        if (arr1[i] == arr1[j]){
            break;
        }
        else{
            arr_1[i] = arr1[i];
        }
    }
    cout << arr_1[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: попробуйте выполнить ваш код по строчкам, тогда вы поймёте, что программа делает что-то не то в цикле. Только сделайте число элементов поменьше, чтобы было проще. И вместо k=false логичнее просто выходить из цикла, он всё равно пользы больше не принесёт

Comment: если Вы знаете в чем проблема, пожалуйста скажите, я еще начинающий могу не понять. Я конкретно НЕ знаю как выполнить эту задачу.

Comment: вы всё делаете правильно, просто нужно научиться кропотливо искать проблему, это часто придётся делать, если собираетесь программировать) я могу вам расписать на что обратить внимание при поиске ошибок, за вас я писать не буду, уж простите

Comment: Но первый элемент все равно нужно записать же?

Comment: С чего вы взяли, вдркг весь arr1 состоит из одних и тех же чисел

Comment: Тоже верно. Я исправил, но все равно не работает.

Comment: Если не разберетесь, через пару часов я напишу вам ответ с более или менее подробными объяснениями

Comment: Сейчас не могу вам сказать, уже не за компьютером. Напишите подробно, если вам не трудно. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнём решать "в лоб". По сути просто исправим ваш код, но я всё же прокомментирую основные моменты данного решения.
Итак, мы про ходим по всем элементам массива А, и, если элемент уникальный(для проверки снова пробегаемся по массиву А в поисках такого же), записываем в массив В. Получаем сложность O(n^2), где n-количество элементов в A.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int const length = 20;
    int A[length];
    cout << "Исходный массив: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        A[i] = -20 + rand() % 41;
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n\n";

    int B[length];
    int B_logical_length = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        //проверка на уникальность
        //тут я в комментариях наговорил ерунды, и пробегать надо всё таки весь массив А
        bool unique = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            if (A[j] == A[i] && j != i)
            {
                unique = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (unique)
        {
            B[B_logical_length] = A[i];
            ++B_logical_length;
        }
    }

    cout << "Результирующий массив: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < B_logical_length; i++)
    {
        cout << B[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Всё это отлично работает при сравнительно небольших объемах данных. Если же у нас довольно большой массив, из-за высокой сложности предыдущий алгоритм может работать довольно медленно.

Попытаемся слегка его усовершенствовать.

Довольно очевидно, что нам в любом случае придётся перебирать все элементы из А(обозначим этот процесс за (1)), это как минимум n действий. Следовательно следует уменьшить время затрачиваемое на проверку уникальности элемента. Этого можно добиться предварительно отсортировав элементы А. Способов сортировки множество, нас интересуют те, временная сложность которых лучше O(n^2).  Преимущество отсортированых данных можно увидеть на следующем примере.
Пусть у нас есть некоторый набор чисел и после сортировки он выглядит следующим образом: 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9.
Видно, что, чтобы проверить элемент на уникальность, достаточно рассмотреть следующий элемент, что мы можем вполне можем сделать в процессе перебора массива А.

В результате получаем сложность приблизительно равную сложности выбранного алгоритма сортировки

**n.b.**
Можете попытаться реализовать 2ой алгоритм для тренировки

Comment: Если говорить об эффективности, то стоит упомянуть возможность использования доп структур (хеша или дерева)...

Comment: @Fat-Zer наверное вы правы, но я хотел лишь показать как можно улучшить интуитивный(1ый) алгоритм. Я в это время как-то даже не думал про другие структуры данных, ибо в вопросе написано про массив. И я кстати не уверен, что в конечном итоге какое-нибудь дерево или хэштаблица покажут лучшую эффективность по времени

Comment: по эффективности, хеш будет асимптотически работать за `O(N)`... дерево — всегда за `O(N*log(U))`, где `U`— количество уникальных элементов... но OP'у это конечно всё ещё рано учить, впрочем как и то, что такое какой-нить `qsort`, так что я упомянул только для справки...

Comment: @Fat-Zer да, в среднем хэш и правда будет работать быстрее, я затупил. Если вы не против я воспользуюсь вашей идеей и дополню ответ, или, что лучше, сделайте это сами

Comment: конечно не против ;)... сам я не соберусь в ближайшее время...

Comment: Если диапазон значений элементов массива небольшой, то можно эффективно и с малыми затратами на память использовать 2 битовых множества вместо хэш-таблицы. Скажем, для символов (или `uin8_t`) под оба множества потребуется массив из 8 `uint64_t` (512 бит)

Answer (score 0):

Если можно пользоваться библиотекой С++, то

```
int const length = 20;
int arr1[length];

cout << "Исходный массив: \n";
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    arr1[i] = -20 + rand() % 41;
    cout << arr1[i] << " ";
}
cout << "\n\n";

cout << "Результирующий массив: \n";

sort(arr1,arr1+length);
int * end = unique(arr1,arr1+length);

for (int i = 0; i < end - arr1; i++) {
    cout << arr1[i] << " ";
}
cout << "\n\n";
```

В вашем массиве первые `end - arr1` элементов теперь уникальны. Можно их перекопировать, куда надо.

А можно сначала перекопировать все, а потом выполнить этот код для нового массива.

Comment: Нет, библиотекой я пока не могу и не умею пользоваться. В том то и дело.